# Is there a way to find out presence of binary code in an uploaded file or text area in ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to stop users from uploading files or entering binary data in text area in front-end. I am unable to find a method in ruby or javascript to check the presence of binary code in the submission made by the user on my website.

```
  var binary_count = 0;
  var isAscii = true;
  //binary check
  for (var i=0, len=submission.length; i<len; i++){
        if (submission[i] > 127){ 
          isAscii=false; 
          binary_count += 1;
          $('.error').html('Binary code is not allowed in submission.').show();
          break;
          }
    }
```

This method does not work in javascript and I am also unable to find a way to check it in rails too.
Can any one guide me in this case?

Comment: assuming `submission` is a string, it should be `submission.charCodeAt(i) > 127`

Comment: If I am pasting the same binary code in the text area and submitting it. It doesnt detect the binary code. Is it that its encoding changes to UTF-8 and can this code  harm the system in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't properly check this user submission in javascript, because there always are possible submit data without javascript checks. So you should validate it in rails. Your validation can be something like this (not tested).

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   validate :proper_string
   def proper_string
     errors.add(:submission, "Only text allowed") unless submission.force_encoding("UTF-8").valid_encoding? 
   end
end
```

With javascript you can validate only for usability reason, but there look more like hacking attempt, but not user mistake.

Comment: Thanks this worked, it was able to detect image submitted as binary file.

Comment: If I am pasting the same binary code in the text area and submitting it. It doesnt detect the binary code. Is it that its encoding changes to UTF-8 and can this code harm the system in any way?

Comment: System can be harmed not only with binary code. Simple javascript code can harm system, its depends what you are doing with submitted data.
Try change unless part with `submission.split("").select{|s| s.ord > 127}.empty?` It exactly check in some way how in your previous javascript example.